# NodeJS/Meteor how to download many files from external server through request.get and future?

Tags: node.js, meteor, web-scraping, future

I'm currently having a problem when trying to download many images through a external request.get, bellow are the code

```
var future = new Future();
var images, nome, blob;

.each(imoveis, function(dadosImovel, numeroImovel){

   images = dadosImovel.images;

   _.each(imagens, function(value, key){

      // the name of the image to a permalink format, this function is working
      nome = Meteor.createPermalinkFromString(value[3]);

      // the link pointing to the image
      blob = Meteor.getImage(value[0]);

      Meteor.saveImage(blob, nome, '.jpeg');
   });
});

// Get a image through a url
Meteor.getImage = function(url){

    var options = {
        url : url,
        encoding : null
    };

    // get raw image
    request.get(options, function(error, result, body) {

        if (error) {
            return console.error(error);
        }

        //  pause until binaries are fully loaded
        future['return'](body);

    });

    return future.wait()
};

// save a image in a server folder
Meteor.saveImage = function(name, blob, ext, encoding) {

    var projectPath = basepath.resolve('.').split('.meteor')[0],
        chroot  = Meteor.chroot || projectPath + 'public', // (process.env['PWD'] +'/public') ;
        path    = chroot + (path ? '/' + path + '/' : '/'),
        name    = Meteor.cleanName(name || 'file'),
        encoding= encoding || 'binary';


    // TODO Add file existance checks, etc...
    fs.writeFile(path + name + ext, blob, encoding, function(err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            throw (new Meteor.Error(500, 'Failed to save file.', err));
        } else {
            console.log('The file ' + name + ' (' + encoding + ') was saved to ' + path);
        }
    });

    return true;
}
```

Now here what happens: in the first iteration of the loop I receive the image just fine, the problem appears for the next ones iterations.

If I have, 10 images all of then are saved with 10 different names (and they also have 10 links pointing to the correct images link) but when you visualize the image it's the first image on the list save for all the other 9, it's like once the first image is loaded meteor don't wait for the next binary/image codes to arrive before saving then.

Any thoughts on how to fix this?

Comment: I am guessing but you share the variable `blob` across all you function calls to saveImage().  How would the second call know not to execute when `blob` gets returned by the first future? So maybe `var blob = Meteor.getImage(value[0]);`.

Comment: I did something with that idea but with some difference. I set var future = new Future(); inside getImage function, now for each request there is a new future wait

Answer (score 0):

Changing the

```
var Future = new Future();
```

from the outter scope to inside the function getImage fixed the issue with the images, but created another one.

My current code is

```
        _.each(imoveis, function(dadosImovel, numeroImovel){

            var imagens = dadosImovel.imagens;

            _.each(imagens, function(value, key){

                var nome = Meteor.createPermalinkFromString(value[3]);

                var blob = Meteor.getImage(value[0]);

                Meteor.saveImage(blob, nome, '.jpeg');

            });
        });
```

And now I have a infinite outer loop, saving again and again only the set of images from the first item of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

For referente (in case this might help someone in the future) this is the code I used to make this works:

```
// imovel[0] = link, imovel[1] = width, imovel[2] = height, imovel[3] = title, imovel[4] =               codigo
    var futures = _.map(links, function(imovel) {

    var future = new Future();

    var onComplete = future.resolver();

    var options = {
            url : imovel[0],
            encoding : null
        };

    // get raw image
    request.get(options, function(error, result, body) {

        if (error) {
             return console.error(error);
        }

        var nome = Meteor.createPermalinkFromString(imovel[3]);
        var data = {'codigo' : imovel[4], 'blob' : body, 'nome' : nome};

        onComplete(error, data);
    });

    return future;
});

// wait for all futures to finish
Future.wait(futures);

// and grab the results out.
links    = _.invoke(futures, 'get');
```

Comment: You may need to add `onComplete( error, null);` in your error handling in the `request.get` callback.  I think all futures need to resolve or the wait never ends.